# BelongsTo relation Laravel 5.4 not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two models (see below). With a one to many relationship, the HasMany relationship is working as expected, but the inverse belongsTo doesn't get any results when I try to do this.

```
$user = Auth::user();

dd($user->location->name);
```

I have the following database structure

Table locations

```
id
name
slug
```

Table users

```
id
name
email
password
location_id
remember_token
```

App/User model

```
public function location() {
    return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Models\Location' );
}
```

and the App\Models\Location model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Comment: Is the namespace of `Location` model correct?

Comment: I checked that it's `App\Models\Location` only the User model is outside the Models namespace. I have the one to many relation working on other models who are both living inside the App\Models namespace so maybe I should try to move this.

Comment: Try to explicity add the column name as a parameter and check if it works... `return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Models\Location', 'location_id' );`

Comment: No doesn't work, when I do `$user->location()` I get the error `Call to a member function location() on null`

Comment: I think I've found the problem `Auth::user()` is not returning logged in user (update yep that's it...)

Comment: If you `dd($user)`, is it correct?

Comment: I was about to ask this!! Now it is going to work!

Comment: Yeah it is working thanks for helping! I was checking the auth::user somewhere it's not defined yet :)